# developing GUI application without using GUI toolkit

Tags: c++, c, user-interface

Is it possible to write GUI application without using GUI toolkit ? As the GUI toolkit like GTK+ itself is written in c language, when there were no such toolkits at starting so how could programmers developed GUI apps only using c or c++ without using such toolkits?  How can one write Gui application in c or c++ without using any GUI toolkit?

Comment: This makes your application operating system (OS) dependent. You can use Win32/MFC, but its messy, has tons of bugs kept untouched for compatibility reasons, etc. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Recently I have started building the GUI using HTTP and HTML. The C++ application basically opens up a server socket and delivers the GUI in HTML using the HTTP protocol. The GUI itself is a set of HTML templates whose data elements are filled in "on the fly" and javascript and AJAX is used to communicate data back to the C++ application.

Comment: Yes.  It is also possible to mow a football pitch with a pair of scissors.

Answer (score 4):

You can program Windows GUI applications using the Win32 API directly, without using any separate toolkit like GTK+.  One reference on how to do that is here: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/start.html

It's not so common these days, and not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 3):

Doing GUI stuff at the API level in Windows is not difficult, but involves a lot of work.

As a starting point you can check out my old Windows API programming tutorial [“Lessons in Windows API Programming (C++)”](http://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/).

Going that route you would do well to obtain a copy of the 5<sup>th</sup> edition or earlier (not 6<sup>th</sup> or later) of Charles Petzold’s “Programming Windows”, which is considered the Bible on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

You start with a frame buffer for the graphics, upon that you write a set of primitive functions to do basic geometry (lines, circles, polygons, bit copies). Then you create an event queue, and a way to populate it with input events (keyboard, mouse, etc.).

You'll also need to create font and text routines.

Those are the basics upon which any GUI are built, as basic guis are little more than boxes that take click events, and eventually keyboard events.

It's a lot of work.

If you want to look at GUI programming at a lower level, consider looking up are it was originally done in the primitve OSes (such as early Windows, early Mac OS, early X Windows).

Mac OS made much of the work explicit. It offered a Window Manager, and other high level controls, but with a bit of study you can see how these were built on top of Quickdraw (MacOS graphics primitive library).

None of this addresses the modern issue of GPU acceleration and the like, that's a completely different layer of complexity to the problem.